# Image Button appears in different location on Emulator than on Graphical Layout

Tags: android, button, android-emulator

I'm using an image button for an an app that im creating and the trouble is the graphical layout shows the button in a different place than when running on the emulator. I've posted my code below plz help. I have provided a dropbox link of the Graphical Layout vs whats displayed on the Emulator. The image button is the red play button and on the pic on the left it appears out of bounds while on the emulator it's perfectly placed on the Red Play button. Note: Im placing a button over an image of the same button. Here is the link : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8104708/Comparison.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/title_screen" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibPlay"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
        android:background="@drawable/box_side_red"
        android:onClick="@drawable/box_side_red_pressed_shadow" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post a screenshots of what you want and what you get...

Comment: can you post sketch that how do you want to display imagebutton exactly??

Comment: What do you undersand under "different places" ? Put screenshots here and say how it looks on the phone and how it looks on the emulator. Or create a scetch of the result at least.

Comment: My sincerest apologies im very new to this, i will upload the screenshots momentarily

Comment: The image is uploaded thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may be it works fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/mango"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibPlay"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/apple" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help but in this case i believe that in both the emulator and the graphical layout the button is created in the same spot. My issue arises when i try to move the button to my desired location. Also in the xml im getting the follow warning for layout_alignParentBotton/Right , "Invalid Layout Param"

Comment: r u using Relative Layout or LinearLayout ?

Comment: Even when using the Relative Layout the problem still persists :(. It even shows different sizes of the button now when comparing the emulator to the Graphical Layout.